# bootstrap3 form has text overlapping with dropdown

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to create a form that looks like this:
[image: Mockup]

What I have come up with looks like this.  I either can have the dropdown take up the correct amount of space, but then the text is underneath, or have the text next to the dropdown and everything gets smushed.
[image: Reality]

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.  Here is the html:

```
<form class="schedulerBody form-horizontal" id="{{sourceCleaned}}">
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">{{t "templates.scheduler.fireEvery"}}</label>
    <div class="col-sm-8">
        <div class="form-inline">
            <div class="form-group">
                <select class="liveSyncSchedule form-control"></select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">{{t "templates.scheduler.seconds"}}</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-8">
        <div class="checkbox">
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox" />{{t "templates.scheduler.enabled"}}
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-8">
        <div class="checkbox">
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox" />{{t "templates.scheduler.persisted"}}
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">{{t "templates.scheduler.misfirePolicy"}}</label>
    <div class="col-sm-8">
        <select class="misfirePolicy form-control">
            <option value="fireAndProceed">{{t "templates.scheduler.fireAndProceed"}}</option>
            <option value="doNothing" selected>{{t "templates.scheduler.doNothing"}}</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

All help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simplified fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mz1xgr38/

```
<form class="form-horizontal">

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Fire every</label>
        <div class="col-sm-9">

            <div class="row">

                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <select class="form-control">
                        <option>1</option>
                        <option>2</option>
                        <option>3</option>
                    </select>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-6">
                    Seconds
                </div>

            </div>

        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-9 ">
            <div class="checkbox">
                <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" />Enabled
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class="checkbox">
                <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" />Persisted
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Misfire policy</label>
        <div class="col-sm-9">
            <select class="form-control">
                <option>Option 1</option>
                <option>Option 2</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>

</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

The layout is messed because `form-group` class is not handled properly. Try this,

```
<form class="schedulerBody form-horizontal" id="{{sourceCleaned}}">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">{{t "templates.scheduler.fireEvery"}}</label>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
            <div class="form-inline">
                <select class="liveSyncSchedule form-control"></select>
                <span>{{t "templates.scheduler.seconds"}}</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-8">
            <div class="checkbox">
                <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" />{{t "templates.scheduler.enabled"}}
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-8">
            <div class="checkbox">
                <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" />{{t "templates.scheduler.persisted"}}
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">{{t "templates.scheduler.misfirePolicy"}}</label>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
            <select class="misfirePolicy form-control">
                <option value="fireAndProceed">{{t "templates.scheduler.fireAndProceed"}}</option>
                <option value="doNothing" selected>{{t "templates.scheduler.doNothing"}}</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Neither response was perfect but I did figure it out with the help.  Thanks guys!